# Python mypy Annotation Decorators __call__

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to annotate a decorator implemented as a class, but mypy seems to either lose the annotation or lose the type and think it's an Any.
What I am trying to annotate:

```
class my_decorator:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

@my_decorator
def func():
    return 2
```

How do I annotate this so func is detected as returning an int after decorating?
I realize the above looks simple and I could convert my_decorator to a function, but in reality it is subclassed to have more specialized options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make `my_decorator` a [generic class](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html) and do something like the following:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class my_decorator(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, func: Callable[..., T]) -> None:
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> T:
        return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

@my_decorator
def func() -> int:
    return 2
```

That is, capture the return type of your function using a TypeVar, which is scoped to your `my_decorator` class. This ensures the value bound to TypeVar is "available" when we try making use of it when analyzing any invocations of `__call__`.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to ensure that the parameters of `__call__` will match the parameters of `func()`. So, mypy won't report an error if you try doing something like `func(1, 2, 3)`.

This may become possible once mypy adds support for [PEP 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/), which adds better support for typing decorator-related code in general.